# Unit testing Angular directive with templateUrl and triggerHandler

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I try to write unit test for my example directive, but if I replace `template` on `templateUrl` then `element.triggerHangler` does not trigger directive events and I don't understand why.

My directive

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('chatEditor', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        onAdd: '&'
      },
      templateUrl: 'chat/chat-editor.directive.html',
      /*template: '<div></div>'*/
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {
          scope.onAdd({message: 'test'});
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Unit test

```
'use strict';

describe('chatEditor', () => {
  beforeEach(module('app', 'templates'));

  it('should add player', inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
    $rootScope.onAddSpy = jasmine.createSpy('onAddSpy');
    const element = $compile('<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"></chat-editor>')($rootScope);

    element.triggerHandler('click');

    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect($rootScope.onAddSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
  }));
});
```

got error

> Expected spy onAddSpy to have been called with [ 'test' ] but it was never called.

but if I comment out `templateUrl` and uncomment `template` then test successful pass.

Also I installed and configured `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor`. My cut from `karma.conf.js`

```
...

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'app/**/*.module.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  'app/**/*.html'
],

preprocessors: {
  'app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  stripPrefix: 'app/',
  //prependPrefix: 'app/'
  moduleName: 'templates'
},
...
```

but it doesn't solve problem.

Comment: The first thing I would check is whether the template is actually picked up by `html2js`. To do so, inject `$templateCache` into your test and see what `$templateCache.get('chat/chat-editor.directive.html')` returns

Comment: @crizzis yes I checked `$templateCache.get('chat/chat-editor.directive.html')` and my template returns successfully.

Comment: @crizzis and if I test my directive manually from browser then all worked as expected.

Comment: Is the content of your template `<div></div>` as well? Which browser are you launching karma in? Some browsers (most notably PhantomJS) fail to handle `triggerHandler` correctly in unit tests, but that wouldn't explain why an inline template works

Comment: @crizzis yes I tried to put content between `<div></div>`, but it doesn't solve problem. I am launching karma in chrome browser. If I put template manually into cache `$templateCache.put('chat/chat-editor.directive.html', '<div></div>')` then the problem remain, i.e unlikely it is a problem of `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor`.

Comment: @crizzis I found that the problem is raised because `$compile('<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"></chat-editor>')($rootScope)` return `<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"></chat-editor>` if `templateUrl` is used and return `<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"><div></div></chat-editor>` if `template` is used. Simply put, the template does not compile with `templateUrl`, but as fix this problem I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

After long time I understood what is the problem. Because `templateUrl` is asynchronous, then template can't be loaded synchronous during the unit test and respectively after compile phase we get `<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"></chat-editor>` element instead `<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"><div></div></chat-editor>`

In order to fix the problem can use several approaches.

### 1) Move the compile phase to beforeEach block

```
'use strict';

describe('chatEditor', () => {
  let element;

  beforeEach(module('app', 'templates'));

  beforeEach(inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
    element = $compile('<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"></chat-editor>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should add player', inject($rootScope => {
    $rootScope.onAddSpy = jasmine.createSpy('onAddSpy');

    element.triggerHandler('click');
    expect($rootScope.onAddSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
  }));
});
```

### 2) Use $timeout

```
'use strict';

describe('chatEditor', () => {
  beforeEach(module('app', 'templates'));

  it('should add player', inject(($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) => {
    $rootScope.onAddSpy = jasmine.createSpy('onAddSpy');

    const element = $compile('<chat-editor on-add="onAddSpy(message)"></chat-editor>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    $timeout(() => {
      element.triggerHandler('click');
      expect($rootScope.onAddSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
    });

    $timeout.flush();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried solution #2 without using `$timeout`? It seems to me that calling `$rootScope.$digest()` before `triggerHandler` should already solve the problem

Comment: @crizzis yes you are right. Enough call `$rootScope.$digest` right after $compile that solve the problem. I will update my answer a bit later.